# How to check my array is single array or multi array (arrays inside array) in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two type of array.

First type

```
 $arr = [1,2,3];
```

Second type

```
$arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
```

How to check that my array is single or multi array.

I am using below code which is always giving me as **Multi Array**

```
 if(is_array($arr)){   
   echo "Multi Array"; 
 } else{   
   echo "SingleArray"; 
 }
```

Comment: `if(is_array($arr) and is_array($arr[0]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking if you can check for your array being multi-dimensional, to which end, I came up with a function not so long ago;

```
<?php
function is_multidimensional(array $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $part)
    {
        if (is_array($part)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$is_md_array = is_multidimensional($myarray); // True if it is, false if not
```

There is nothing to say that this can't be made fully recursive to check further down the array too, but this is a good start if you need this more often than once

Comment: What would be the point to 'check further down the array too'? Once a sub-array is detected you can stop, so you will never get 'further down'.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - I have had to extend this to traverse further down the arrays, simply because I knew that the first 2 / 3 steps were going to be MD (from JSON in this case), but needed to know if after a certain level of steps it ended being MD for audit logs and trails

Answer (score 1):

**This attempt is not as good as Sam Swift's answer** as it does not *stop on the 1st array encountered* and it *can be slow with large arrays* because of `in_array()`.
But here it is:

```
// This will contain an array of boolean (is the item an array or not)
$are_arrays = array_map( function ($a) {
    return is_array($a);
}, $arr );

// This will return if true is found in our previous array
$is_multi = in_array(true, $are_arrays);


// Output debug
var_dump($is_multi);
```

It can fit into one single line for a "*quick check*":

```
$is_multi = in_array(true, array_map(function ($a) { return is_array($a); }, $arr));
```

- [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)
- [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Comment: Clever, but rather difficult to understand. It also does more work than is needed because it doesn't stop as soon as an array in an array is found.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware you are right, Sam Swift's answer is the best I think. I'll edit to mark it as "attempt" I guess

Comment: I personally really like this - it's a great example of what can be done to achieve the same result, yes a performance hit will happen with larger arrays, but for the quick checks, I love this solution, you've taught me something new, thanks!